# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS compatible with Dell 2950's through auto provisioning?

Tags: server, dell, ram

Was wondering if Ubuntu 12.04 is supported on Dell 2950's through a RAM disk image?

Answer (score 1):

12.04 should work on the 2950 for auto provisioning. We don't have a preconfigured version though. All you will need to do is ensure the nic (bnx2) and the controller driver (mpt2sas) must be in the initrd file for it to see the perc controllers.
What controller do you have installed?